# Codesign No identity found

Tags: macos, certificate, identity, codesign

I am trying to use Codesign in the Terminal like follows:

```
codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: asdf" -v "My App.app"
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
3rd Party Mac Developer Application: asdf: no identity found
```

Any ideas?  Basically, codesign cannot "see" this certificate.  But, no matter how I type it out, I get the same error.  I tried the following:

```
codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: asdf" -v "My App.app"
codesign -f -s 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: asdf -v "My App.app"
codesign -f -s 3rd\ Party\ Mac\ Developer\ Application:\ asdf -v "My App.app"
codesign -f -s asdf -v "My App.app"
codesign -f -s "asdf" -v "My App.app"
codesign -f -s Application -v "My App.app"
```

Specifically, I am trying to get my app into the Mac App Store.  Is this a problem with provisioning or something?  I feel like I've tried everything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I re-created the certificates and this solved the problem.  The reason that I posted this question is because I had re-created the certificates before, to no avail.

However, the '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: asdf' certificate was missing the private key, for some reason.

Comment: The private key is generated upon install *if* you obtained the certificate from your own/correct developer account. A fellow team member had emailed me a .cer file, which is how I encountered this issue and figured that out. There must be a personal ID in the .cer file that triggers the creation of the key when it's installed.